# Desktop LEDs working but not booting to BIOS or anything else

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, power-supply, desktop-computer

I have an older desktop computer with an amd "*m2n4 sli*" asus motherboard that i occasionally turn on once in a week/month or something like that.

Recently, i have turned it on and it booted up normally at first. The computer went into windows xp and everything seemed fine. Except it turned off after 1-5 minutes. I have tried repeating turning the computer back on but it always turned off by itself after a little while (except from that it worked perfectly fine). So i thought that maybe it's an OS issue, so i booted into BIOS, waited for a while and the same thing happened- it turned off after some seconds.

Now i thought that this could be either something overheating or the power supply unit. I have tried turning the PSU off completely and went to do other things. When i came back after 15 minutes and turned it back on nothing happened. The computer just powers up, some LEDs shine, the network cable is receiving power as well, fans spin but computer doesn't boot at all. not even into bios; and the monitor is not displaying anything.

I have tried cleaning the insides of all the dust (in case it was overheating), unplugging all the inner hardware and plugging it back again, resetting cmos, even pluging rams off to see if there's a faulty one, nothing.

When i turn the PSU on, **the computer randomly either shuts right back down or stays powered up but there is completely nothing going on**.

Could somebody give me any suggestions on what else to try? Right now i am thinking of buying an unexpensive alternative PSU + CMOS battery to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you recommendations on what to buy is off topic. Any cheap PSU or Power Supply Unit will work just fine as long as you find the proper connections you need for your motherboard, hard drive and CD-rom (if you have one).

Clearly, the power supply sounds like it was beginning to fail. I'm not a PSU expert, so I don't exactly know what is the specific problem. But clearly it's not working.

When hardware begins to die, it sometimes does very weird unexpected things. Especially power supplies, so troubleshooting a computer with a bad PSU ususally takes a bit more effort. So i'm not surprised you're running into these sort of issues.